# Cause of rendundat whitespace on the right of a page

Tags: html, css, width, whitespace, padding

On my website I have whitespace on the right of my page, but all widths in the page are set to 100%, including the color of the page. So even if there was a width that was extending outside the page, this part should be the same color as the rest.

I am using an anchor based website, and if you look at it http://www.jeremyspence.net78.net/ you can see that only on the first anchor is there whitespace on the side, but there is extra space on the side all the way through (obviously). I don't want either the whitespace or the extra space, but the whitespace is perplexing. And yes I have `margin: 0;` and `padding: 0;`

Comment: Please include the relevant code here instead of linking to an external site. If the external site changes or goes away, this question then loses context and becomes useless.

Comment: a quick look at your page source gave this. removing `width: 100%` from your `.mecontainer` class seemed to fix it. Even though there is no explicit width set for it, it still somehow is wider than others. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Understanding the box-model**

In your site, the classes `websitecontainer`, `packagecontainer` and `mecontainer` all have  the following style rules:

```
...
width:100%;
padding:50px;
...
```

This literally means that they should span the full width of their container (the body in this case) and then the browser should *add* 50px of padding around that width. This is the way it should be according to the [W3C standard box-model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/box_model) that is used by modern browsers. In outdated versions of IE, the box-model would have worked the way it is currently setup in your page and the padding would have been *subtracted* from the width.

See the illustration below to understand the difference:

[image: W3C box-model]

**The solution**

The straight forward solution would be to remove the padding from these containers, eliminating the extra width and redundant spacing. If you require that padding, you can simply wrap the contents of the current containers inside another container and apply the padding to this new inner container. For example:

```
 <div class="some-container">
     <div class="inner-container">
          <!--Content goes here as before-->
     </div>
 </div>
```

With the style rules now being:

```
 .some-container {width:100%;}
 .inner-container {padding:50px;}
```

Comment: that's not correct, I don't think. 'Padding' is from 'within' the element. so it wouldn't effect the outside perimeter.

Comment: You could also consider using `box-sizing: border-box;` so that `padding` and `border` are included in the calculated width.

Comment: @mavili That's incorrect. Padding is not included in the width unless it's set that way using the `box-sizing` property. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/box-sizing

Comment: Removing the padding worked thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Replace your current CSS code for these styles with this

```
.websitescontainer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1080px;
    background: #cefece;
}
.packagescontainer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1080px;
    background: #cefefe;
}
.mecontainer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1080px;
    background: #fecefe;
}
```

Note: You can make this code in this way

```
.websitescontainer, .packagescontainer, .mecontainer{
    width: 100%;
    height: 1080px;
    background: #cefece;
}
.mecontainer {
    background: #fecefe;
}
```

Comment: Woah, careful with the `!important`. That's going to mess with other CSS styles if you're not careful.

Comment: Using a star selector to set all the padding to `0` isn't a good solution. The problem is that padding is being set on some of the `div` containers.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS here:

```
.homecontainer {
    background:#ffe6ce;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1080px;
    padding-top:50px;
}
```

Should maybe be:

```
.homecontainer {
    background:#ffe6ce;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1080px;
    padding: 50px 0 0 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Note the addition of `margin` and the reworking of your `padding` to be shorthand format which basically runs clockwise from the top: 50px (top) 0 (right) 0 (bottom) 0 (left)

Answer (score -1):

It looks like removing

```
padding: 50px;
```

from `.mecontainer` solves it.

Comment: @downvoter it's so unhelpful when you downvote without commenting about your reason. Is it too much an effort?